# sharepoint online: How to display document library from root site in subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, xslt-list-view-web-part

How can i display document library in my root site collection in subsites. One way i found [here](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/display-list-from-top-level-site-subsite-in-sharepoint.html)
, its not working as aspected. When i select a view/source and create the webpart in top site gallery and added it on a subsite, it dosent display the fields from the view i selected. And just displays: Name, MOdified, MOdified by, and none of the other fields from the selected view...
[image]

If i delete the webpart from my subsite, and add it again, i can se my fields from the view, but only when iam in "Edit page" mode. As soon as i save the page, or go out from the "Edit page" mode webpart displays as pic above.
**In Edit Mode**
[image]

What i want to acchieve is to display document library from my root site in all subsites. Is there any other good way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Content Query Webpart.

Add the webpart into the subsite and then use the webpart properties to configure the list you want to display.